# Save content of zip file in django

Tags: django

Good Day,

I would like to save the content of the zip file. My code works, but they save only the filename and not the content or actual files neither in the database nor the project.

I need to save in the database the content of each file. Can someone please help me to fix my error? My code looks like this:

```
uploaded_file, = request.FILES.getlist('document[]')
                with zipfile.ZipFile(uploaded_file.file, mode="r") as archive:
                    for zippedFileName in archive.namelist():
                            newZipFile = UploadedFile(document= zippedFileName)
                            newZipFile.user= request.user
                            files = newZipFile.save()
                            success=True
                return render(request, 'uploader/index.html', {'files': [uploaded_file]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people looking on how to save the content of a zip file, this solution works for me

```
IMAGE_FILE_TYPES = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']

def PostCreate(request):
form = PostForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_pr = form.save(commit=False)
        user_pr.album_image = request.FILES['album_image']
        with zipfile.ZipFile(user_pr.album_image, mode="r") as archive:
            for fileName in archive.namelist():
                file_type = fileName.split('.')[-1]
                file_type = file_type.lower()
                if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                    print("ERROR!!!")
                else:
                    file= archive.extract(fileName, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'UnzippedFiles')                        
                    rbe = Post.objects.create(album_image=file)
                    rbe.save()
                    print("SUCESS!!!")
        return render(request, 'photos/post.html', {'user_pr': user_pr})

context = {"form": form,}
return render(request, 'photos/post_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your zipfile on your filesystemstorage : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/files/storage/

Or you can use a BinaryField in your models and try to save your zipfile as encoded binary : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield

THe better way is clearly the usage of a FS i think

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I tried to use FileSystemStorage, but it creates a new folder in my project and saves the file as a zip. I want to save read, extract and save the file in my database and not the name of the file

Comment: there is only two solutions, as i exposed in my response i think. If you want to store integrality of your zip files in db, you have to define a binaryfield instead of your filefield

Comment: Thanks @lucas but it still does not do what I would like to do

Comment: you ask for saving zip file directly in your db ? a BinaryField can do that, you just need to encode your zip into a binary array. Please reexplain your problem if it is not what i say

Comment: Not saving the zip file directly in memory, I want to save the content of the zip file both in memory and database

Comment: What do you mean by memory ? on the disk ? And what do you mean by "content of the zip file" ? You want to unzip the zip file and save each files which it contains ?

Comment: I don't want to save the zip file. I want to save its content in my database and in the project for e.g in media. Currently, it is saving the content of the Zip file as a name only I think it's because I extract it from namelist(). Perhaps, that's why I cannot find the files saved in my media.